# SQL connection not connecting to Claims database

Tags: c#, asp.net, claims-based-identity

I cant connect to my claims database on a copy of a [github project](https://github.com/mmacneil/AngularASPNETCore2WebApiAuth/blob/master/src/Controllers/AccountsController.cs). I keep getting:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

I'm able to connect using the same connection string in another project, but not this one. Are there any files besides appsettings.json I need to change?

**appsettings.json**

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=xxx.206;Database=test_MIM; User ID = me; Password= notpassword;Trusted_Connection=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
```

Comment: I think the error message (and your assertion that the connection string works elsewhere) clearly indicates that this is not an ASP.NET configuration issue. There is some problem connecting to the server, and it's impossible to say what it might be.

Comment: Follow the message: "Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections."